# "Today the weather was snowy" or "The weather was snowy today"?

Tags: verbs, pronouns

```
"Today the weather was snowy"
```

Or

```
"The weather was snowy today"
```

Which sentence is more correct according to the grammer rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct just with a subtle difference.

adverbs of time and definite frequency like today,afterwards,... are common to be used both **at the begining** of a sentence and also **at the end** of the sentence.

The front position is common if the adverb is not the main focus of the message.

> "Today the weather was snowy"
>   the main focus of the message is the fact that today the weather was snowy
>
> "The weather was snowy today"
>   In this sentence you're both focusing on the fact that the weather was snowy and it was today

For more information see **Practical English Usage(23)**